# Creating a calculator in TkInter, text field displacing buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, grid, tkinter, calc

I'm trying to make a calculator using the grid format in tkinter but the text field is displacing the buttons.

I am a beginner to Python and simply stuck.

This is my part of source code:

```
from Tkinter import*


#function for about menu 
def about():
    win2=Tk()
    win2.wm_title("About")
    l=Label(win2,text=" CAL-C ver 1.0 \n Developer. \n Mohd Sanad",padx=5,pady=40)
    l.pack()

win=Tk()#creating window
win.wm_title("CAL-C")#changing window title
#Initiliazing about menu button
menubar=Menu(win)
menubar.add_command(label="About",command=about)
win.config(menu=menubar)


v=StringVar()
e=Entry(win,textvariable=v)
e.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky=W+E)
b1=Button(win,text="1")
b2=Button(win,text="2")
b3=Button(win,text="3")
b4=Button(win,text="4")
b5=Button(win,text="5")
b6=Button(win,text="6")
b7=Button(win,text="7")
b8=Button(win,text="8")
b9=Button(win,text="9")
b1.grid(row=1,column=0)
b2.grid(row=1,column=1)
b3.grid(row=1,column=2)
b4.grid(row=2,column=0)
b5.grid(row=2,column=1)
b6.grid(row=2,column=2)
b7.grid(row=3,column=0)
b8.grid(row=3,column=1)
b9.grid(row=3,column=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial below provides a good insight into how you can use the different layout managers in TkInter, and there is also a example on how to create a calculator.

http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/layout/

**Edit:**

I think the reason why the text field is displacing the button, is because the entry field and the three first buttons  are placed in the same row, and no columns are specified for the text field. I think this causes the entry field to default to the 0 column, and therefore displace the button.

What you could try is to place the entry field in its own row and make it strech over several columns using columnspan and add sticky=W+E to make it expand in the column, like so:

```
v=StringVar()
e=Entry(win,textvariable=v)
# the columnspan make the entry widget strech over more columns
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)

b1.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=W+E)
b2.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W+E)
b3.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=W+E)
b4.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=W+E)
b5.grid(row=2,column=1, sticky=W+E)
b6.grid(row=2,column=2, sticky=W+E)
b7.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=W+E)
b8.grid(row=3,column=1, sticky=W+E)
b9.grid(row=3,column=2, sticky=W+E)
```

Here is an example which renders correctly on my computer:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, W, E
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style
from ttk import Entry

class Example(Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

 def initUI(self):
    e=Entry(self)
    b1 = Button(self, text="1")
    b2 = Button(self, text="2")
    b3 = Button(self, text="3")
    b4 = Button(self, text="4")
    b5 = Button(self, text="5")
    b6 = Button(self, text="6")
    b7 = Button(self, text="7")
    b8 = Button(self, text="8")
    b9 = Button(self, text="9")

    e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)
    b1.grid(row=1,column=0)
    b2.grid(row=1,column=1)
    b3.grid(row=1,column=2)
    b4.grid(row=2,column=0)
    b5.grid(row=2,column=1)
    b6.grid(row=2,column=2)
    b7.grid(row=3,column=0)
    b8.grid(row=3,column=1)
    b9.grid(row=3,column=2)

    self.pack()

def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: that did not work,see i tried this: 
    v=StringVar()
    e=Entry(win,textvariable=v)
    e.grid(row=0,column=1)
    b1.grid(row=1,column=0)
    b2.grid(row=1,column=1)
    b3.grid(row=1,column=2)
    b4.grid(row=2,column=0)



but its better but why there is space between every coulmn of numbers like 1,4,7 r together then some 10 spaces right 2,4,8 are nicely and 10 spaces away 3,6,9 ,if i see clearly the first column is just below before the start of text field in left corner,second just below midpoint of it and third just below end of it in right corner,without text field its fine.

Comment: I think I might have figured it out. Try to add: 
column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E to e.grid(row=0)
it should then look like this:
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)

I will edit the answer to reflect the changes

Comment: almost perfect but what is the use of parent,frame and initUI?
my code looks very crude compared to yours please tell i'm editing it in my question

Comment: what is parent and how can we use it?

Comment: please check my full code in the question

Comment: To seperate the construction of the UI into a method (Here: initUI) is just a habit of mine to make the code easier to read. Declearing the parent is just useful for larger programs were you need to know the parent to add other frames (like popup windows etc). The call to Frame.__init__ is just to setup the resources which Frame uses. The way you are doing it is just as correct. And the Frame itself is just a class include in TkInter which provides a starting point for basic UIs. I think it does this by default when you call Tk() in your code

Comment: i wanted to make a separate function for UI but couldn't beacause i don't know python much, my background is java ,can you please tell why you are bringing Frame as a parameter in the class? and what does self,parent does one more thing, is parent our parent window? 
and did you ran and saw my code? I still could not fix it
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ah, I see! This way better than my first python gui tho.
The reason why I bring Frame as a parameter, is because it then inherits from Frame, and that way you can use it as a starting block for other GUIs. For example if you later want to create a list, you can  inherit fro ListBox which then provides you with a basic interface as a startingpoint. Parent is the parent window, and self is just the reference to the instance of the class itself, in away like "this" in java. I ran it, but it unfortunately looks right on my computer

Comment: If you want the buttons to fill the columns, you could add stick=W+E to them as well. Like so:  b1.grid(row=1,column=0, stciky=W+E)

Comment: sticky=W+E does the job! :D for my buttons thanks a ton! that was my problem there was space between the columns of button,but is there any method to control the width of buttons? and please suggest a site to learn more about frame and more about python gui

Comment: No problem! I'm unfortuantly not sure whether you can control the width more precisely. Here are some links to places were you can learn more about different frameworks:

Zetcode - TkInter (http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/)
Effbot - Tkinter (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm)
There is also a lot of tutorials for other python gui frameworks on zetcode